# Raspberry Pi Image on MAAS

Tags: boot, maas, raspberrypi, disk-image

MAAS: 2.6

I need to add cheaper solution as node to my infrastructure, there is a cheap resourceful option raspberry pi 4, So this is real case in real project!

I need to add Raspberry Pi as node to my Infrastructure 

How may I add Raspberry Pi Image on MAAS?

Answer (score 1):

So, MAAS 2.6 has an ARM64 Image selectable in the Images section of Configuration.

The biggest issue with using Raspberry Pi's is getting them to PXE boot correctly.

You will need to follow a combination of tutorials:

[Complete Phase 1](https://linuxhit.com/raspberry-pi-pxe-boot-netbooting-a-pi-4-without-an-sd-card/) to configure your clients to PXE boot. Then you need to provide a suitable DHCP snippet and locate a number of different files in MAAS. Namely, I have not been able to figure out why the PI's timeout when attempting to boot to maas. According to tcpdump the MAAS server recieves the DHCP requests and responds but the pi's timeout. I have adjusted the timeout, other settings on the PI's bootconfig.txt to no avail.

Finally, I think the most difficult issue is power control. With no IPMI or IDRAC/KVM controls there is no way for MAAS to complete commissioning on its own without setting power control to manual. Which removes one of the key features you would want MAAS for.

If these two things can be resolved I think it will be fairly simple however, as of now I know of no functioning PI booting scheme using MAAS.